# How to fix error when using query export to export large data in Laravel

Tags: laravel, export

I want to export the big data (>10K) when I clicked the 'export button'. I tried to use the Yagra Datatable, however it only can export the current page for pagination. so i tried the query export Maatwebsite.  What I did is when 'export' button is clicked, the result will be passed to the excel function and it will export the data into my local machine. My controller is like below:

```php
public function filterQuery(Request $request)
{
    $dataGender = $request->dataGender;
    $ethnicity = $request->ethnicity;



What should I fix so that when I clicked the button, the query will export the result into CSV?
```

Answer (score 0):

`excel()` takes 2 parameters. `Request $request` is sent automatically, but `$type` is not.

```
function excel(Request $request, $type) { ... }
```

Your uri `/custom` doesn't have a parameter, so the only way to send type is by appending it as a GET parameter. (eg. `/custom?type=some_type`)

#### Your options:

1. Put a default value in your excel() function.

```
function excel(Request $request, $type = 'default') { ... }
```

2. Pass a value on your route.

`<a href="{{ route('export_excel.excel') }}?type=some_type" class="btn btn-success">Export to Excel</a>`

3. Remove $type parameter.

```
function excel(Request $request, $type)
function excel(Request $request)
{
    return Excel::create('FILENAME', function ($excel) use ($data) {
        $excel->sheet('mySheet', function ($sheet) use ($data) {
            $sheet->fromArray($data);
        });
    })->download($type);
    })->download('default');
}
```

Comment: Undefined variable: data,  at excel function

Comment: I'm assuming you get your $data some way. Just define `$data = ...` before the return.

Comment: The problem is actually I dont really sure how to pass the $data from query filterQuery() , so the array will be exported using excel()

Comment: That's not really an error. Can't you copy the query directly?

Comment: I've copied the code, but system lag once I run. I think it query all the data from ModifiedDppr table, so thats why its slow.